# Suppressing "extra ';'" error in GCC when -pedantic is on

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-errors

I'm building my program with `-pedantic` flag, which causes an `extra ';'` error (because of a third-party header using a few macros inconsistently; the error is not shown when `-pedantic` is off). I don't really feel like turning `-pedantic` off, and neither do I want to edit the header. Is there any way to suppress this exact error? Like a `-Wno-annoying-semicolon-error` compiler switch or something?

Comment: why do you want to use pedantic? looking at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options it seems there is no way to do what you want. surely if the use of pedantic is merely based on a feeling, you're better off without it ;-)

Comment: Well, not only feeling :) There are some strong recommendations I have to follow

Comment: Hmmm tricky. I don't suppose the third-party header is open source? Any chance of fixing it?

Comment: It actually is open source, so I guess I will try and contact the author. Well, it seems there's no quick workaround for now... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to remove `-pedantic`. Nothing else will work on that case.

Comment: @KyleStrand Not actually "buggy", but not entirely correct, either. I don't remember which library caused me this trouble four years ago, but there was some macro magic which lead to this problem.

Comment: @RomanDmitrienko I even found this proble on catch2 that is continuesly developing under the new standars it is so annoying

Answer (score 7):

You can suppress pedantic warnings for external headers like this:

```
//save compiler switches
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"

//Bad headers with problem goes here
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

//restore compiler switches
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `-isystem` rather then `-I` when passing include paths, then GCC won't warn you about system headers.

For any headers you maintain, just edit them.

Comment: Did not work for me. Included the library with -isystem but warnings still were thrown for the linux->apple cross-compiler, but it certainly works for g++ and clang